# Chrome is not launching when i execute protractor code in jenkins while doing automation testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, testing, automated-tests, protractor

When I try to run protractor code in jenkins , chrome browser is not launching  but the code is executing in jenkins and it is printing failure.Can i know how to launch the chrome browser so that my application can be viewed.
[I have attached the screenshot for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6wEy.png)

When i run the code in vs code ,the code is executed and the chrome browser is launched successfully.
But while implementing the same procedure in jenkins ,the chrome is not launching.

Comment: Have you downloaded the selenium plugin for Jenkins?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.